# Does an HTML element absolutely positioned outside of the viewport area affect the performance of repaint?

Tags: html, css

For example, if I have a `<div>` with style:

```
position: absolute; width: 100px; height: 100px; left: -10000px; top: -10000px;
```

When a repaint of the viewport happen, there is some time loss due to the div's presence in DOM?

NOTE: the `<div>` has `visibility: visible and display: block`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer - yes.

Even though you can't see it, it still has to be rendered into the DOM as you say.

People do this a lot then do some fancy animation to bring it into view. The thing to ask is is there a difference between rendering the whole DOM in one hit or would you save time by rendering each bit, when requested with AJAX ?

It depends on the complexitity of the content in your 'hidden' section(s)...

Edit: Try using Fiddler : http://www.telerik.com/fiddler : this will allow you to see what is taking time to load on your pages...

Comment: ok, thank you for your response! I've another related question, also... but maybe is better to open a new thread! :)

Comment: (+)1 but it's not so...obvious. I mean: yes performance will be affected (somehow) but not as element was inside viewport. Browser will consider them in layout but they won't paint them. If it something _expansive_ to paint (such a highres image or a complex canvas) then there is a measurable difference when it's inside or outside viewport.